# How to set an external function into a function's parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var element;

function getElement(elem, functionToCall) {
  if (elem.length === undefined) {
    elem = [elem]
  };
  element = elem;
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    functionToCall
  }
};

function changeElementStyle() {
  element[i].style.color = "red"
}
getElement(document.querySelectorAll("p"), changeElementStyle);
```

Here's my code, but it doesn't works. What i want is, to be able to set a function(`changeElementStyle`) in a function(`getElement`)'s parameter, which(`changeElementStyle`) is outside the function(`getElement`). The reason why i need to declare the outer function outside the `getElement()` is that the `changeElementStyle()` changes other styles every time it's called.
How can i do that?

Comment: why are you not calling `z()` inside the for loop?

Comment: Those meaningless one-character variable names make the code really hard to read.

Comment: Can't you just do `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(el => el.style.color = 'red');`?

Comment: It's just an example, i need those functions for later use. For a more deep example, i wrote these functions, then i select all of the divs, and set the position of the divs to relative. Then, select paragraphs, set a white colors to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the function `w` without that var declaration

```
function w(i) {
    a[i].style.color = "red"
}
```

Pass the function as follow:

```
x(document.querySelectorAll("p"), w);
```

To call the function `w` you need to execute that function, as you can see that function now receives an index to be able to get the specific element `p`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  z(i); // Here
}
```

```js
var a;

function x(y, z) {
  if (y.length === undefined) {
    y = [y]
  };
  a = y;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    z(i);
  }
};

function w(i) {
  a[i].style.color = "red"
}

x(document.querySelectorAll("p"), w);
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

call closure this way :

```
function myFunc(a){
  a();
}
```

and remember for closure you do not need to define a name . 
you can define a closure and pass it like this

```
f = function(){
  console.log('closure');
}
myFunc(f)
```